# Script Does not work on Cloudrig after regeneration auto executon but it works when I execute it manually

Tags: python, animation, scripting, rigging

Script Does not work on Cloudrig after regeneration auto executon but it works when I execute it manually

```
    import bpy


bone_names = ["TIP-IK-MSTR-Weapon_mech2.R", "TIP-IK-MSTR-Weapon_mech2.L"]


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')

for bone_name in bone_names:
  
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["RIG-Jake"]

   
    bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = bpy.context.object.data.bones[bone_name]

   
    bpy.ops.pose.constraint_add(type='ARMATURE')

   
    constraint = bpy.context.object.pose.bones[bone_name].constraints[-1]

 
    constraint_target = constraint.targets.new()
    constraint_target.target = bpy.data.objects["RIG-Jake"]
    constraint_target.subtarget = "Caseroot"
```